# Update table conditionally based on two columns and multiple rows in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I need to update a foreign key in table 1 with the correct entry based on table 2. The correct foreign key is the earliest date that falls after, but not before the next effective dates in table 2. If there are multiple entries in table 2 with the same effective date, then use the modified date column as a tie breaker and pick the most recent one.  Here is the based table structure (all dates are in Date format):

```
Table 1
pK1   PeriodStartDate               pK2    
1     2016-04-01 00:00:00.000               
2     2016-07-01 00:00:00.000

Table 2
pK2    EffectiveFrom                ModifiedDate
3      2016-03-01 00:00:00.000      2016-04-01 00:00:00.000
4      2016-05-01 00:00:00.000      2016-06-01 00:00:00.000
5      2016-05-01 00:00:00.000      2016-06-02 00:00:00.000
```

So in the above example table 1 would look like this:

```
pK1   PeriodStartDate                  pK2    
1     2016-04-01 00:00:00.000          3     
2     2016-07-01 00:00:00.000          5
```

This is because for row 1 it falls between March 1st and May 1st (from table 2). And for row 2 it is after the last date, but as there are two similar start dates we choose the last modified.

I'm not sure of the solution. I was trying something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET pK2 = table2.pK2
FROM table2 
WHERE PeriodStartDate > (SELECT FIRST(table2.EffectiveFrom) FROM table2)
```

I'm just not sure how to find an entry that is bounded by another row (and then needs another column for the tie breaker)

Comment: Is that how your data is really stored or is that just how you typed it?  It's very cumbersome to do date evaluations based on strings.  Also, what have you tried, please show efforts.

Comment: That's just how I typed it for ease of description. Both columns are DateTime.

Comment: Then you need to fix this... and show your attempts please.

Comment: changes made as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to apply a `row_number()` over `Table2`, partitioned on the `PeriodStart` and ordered by the `ModifiedDate` (desc).  Call this `MaxModified`; and 1 is always the most recently modified record.

```
pK2 PeriodStart             ModifiedDate            MaxModified
3   2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 2016-04-01 00:00:00.000 1
5   2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 2016-06-02 00:00:00.000 1
4   2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000 2
```

Then, for only where `MaxModified=1`, you add a new "id" to this so we can line up a start date, with the next rows start date (our end date).  This is also done with the `row_number()` function ordered by the `PeriodStart`.

```
pK2 PeriodStart             ModifiedDate            MaxModified myID
3   2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 2016-04-01 00:00:00.000 1           1
5   2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 2016-06-02 00:00:00.000 1           2
```

Then we take that result and join it to itself offset by one row to get an end date value for each original row.

```
pK2 PeriodStart             ModifiedDate             MaxModified    myID    PeriodEnd
3   2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 2016-04-01 00:00:00.000  1              1       2016-05-01 00:00:00.000
5   2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 2016-06-02 00:00:00.000  1              2       NULL
```

Once we have that, its a simple matter of joining on the start/end dates to get our `pk2` value.

Full script...

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (pK1 INT, PeriodStart DATETIME, pK2 INT)
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (pK2 INT, PeriodStart DATETIME, ModifiedDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES (1,'2016-04-01',NULL),
       (2,'2016-07-01',NULL)

INSERT INTO @Table2
VALUES (3,'2016-03-01','2016-04-01'),
       (4,'2016-05-01','2016-06-01'),
       (5,'2016-05-01','2016-06-02')

;WITH OrderedList AS
(
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PeriodStart ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC) AS MaxModified
    FROM @Table2
),X AS
    (
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PeriodStart) AS myID
        FROM OrderedList
        WHERE MaxModified=1
    ), Y AS
        (
            SELECT L.*, R.PeriodStart AS PeriodEnd
            FROM X L
            LEFT JOIN X R ON L.myID=R.myID-1 AND R.MaxModified=1
            WHERE L.MaxModified=1
        )

UPDATE T SET pK2=Y.pK2
FROM @Table1 T
LEFT JOIN Y ON T.PeriodStart >= Y.PeriodStart AND T.PeriodStart < COALESCE(Y.PeriodEnd,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

SELECT *
FROM @Table1
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me with this! I've just implemented it in my test DB. Curiously it's updating all of the pK2 columns in table 1 to null. I'm looking into it further.

Comment: Try removing the update, and just selecting from the CTEs : `select top 50 * from y` would be a good start, make sure the end start/end dates line up logically.